# Is it possible to create a controller service on runtime in apache nifi after getting required input fields from GetFile operate?

Tags: controller, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-nifi

I am working on a project where I am assigned to take a configuration file (GetFile operate) as a user input consisting of certain values. Is it possible that same values are then passed onto another operate (still looking for this) that create a controller service while dataflow is being executed?

The requirement is that each user will be updating their own configuration file and it is impossible for us to have controller services created for them beforehand.

Looking forward to any help or guidance.

Comment: Why do you need to create a controller service dynamically? It make no sense by itself. You need a flow that will use this controller... However you can use nifi api to create whatever you can create from browser.

Comment: It was a project requirement - one controller service for as many client/user. I accomplished the same by making use of the variable registry.